# Mobile First Breakpoints for nth child

Tags: css

I have this code that works, it is a group of client icons that starts off with a 2 column list on mobile, then gradually moves to a 3 column list and then onto a 4 column list and so on.

I am using the nth child pseudo element to remove the margin on certain numbers depending on the breakpoint i.e `:nth-child(2n)` on the column breakpoint.

But check my code out I feel it is messy, Does anyone know of a better way to write this?

```
.list-horiz-images li {
float: left;
margin-right: 7px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
width: 49%;

&:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

@include mobilefirst(em(670)) {

    width: 32.57%;

    &:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }

    &:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
}

@include mobilefirst(em(1024)) {

    width: 24.44%;

    &:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }

    &:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }

    &:nth-child(4n) {
        margin-right: 0px;
    }

}


@include mobilefirst(em($bp-large)) {
    width: 13.666666666%;

    &:nth-child(2n) {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }

    &:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }

    &:nth-child(4n) {
        margin-right: 7px;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Are you shure that it is plain css as you tagged it?